# PHP / Laravel - Combine result (Model relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Right now I have below data:

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Now the problem with above is, that it's creating a new array for each entry in my database.

I would very much like to get below output:

[image: Third]

[image: Fourth]

The difference is here that:

- All the routes that are the same, should be grouped. So if the `Route` is the same, it should be under the same route list.
- If the `Carrier` under the route is the same, then it should be under that route **and** carrier
- If the route is different, it should start a new list (**Route: XYZ to XYZ)

## Current Code:

`Controller.php`:

```
public function show()
    {
        $routes = Routes::where('id', '>=', 1)
        ->with('routeStops', 'getVessel')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

        foreach ($routes as $key => $value) {
            echo '<h2>Route: ' . $value['origin'] . ' to ' . $value['destination'] . '</h2>';
            $carrier = Carriers::where('id', $value['get_vessel']['carriers_id'])->first()->name;
            echo 'Carrier: ' . $carrier . '';
            dump($value);
        }

    }
```

This is my models:

`Routes.php`

```
/**
 * Get the route stop associated with this route.
 */
public function routeStops()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RouteStops', 'route_id');
}

/**
* Get the vessel record associated with this route.
*/
public function getVessel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Vessels', 'vessel_id');
}
```

How can I do so I achieve the 2nd desired output?

Comment: Please rework your question so as not to rely on screenshots of "data" and show what effort you have made to solve any problems yourself.

Comment: @miken32 - I have posted the code below the screenshots. I can replace the screenshots with the array strings, but thought it might be more useful to see the desired output visually.
I don't know what more code to post, as I am stuck.

Comment: For someone without images enabled, it's much less useful. "Right now I have below data: The difference is here that:..."